# Move files with ssh

Tags: ssh, files

I know that I can copy files from my computers with scp. Is there a way to move them at once instead of copying with ssh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to mount the SSH using `sshfs`. It's fairly quick, fairly clean and doesn't need root to action. There's a little bit of setup to do (that may actually be optional these days) but you can read about that on [its help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS).

But here's how I just mounted my media centre's home in a subdirectory of my local home:

```
oli@bert:~$ mkdir tim # create a directory to mount on
oli@bert:~$ sshfs oli@tim:/home/oli tim
oli@bert:~$ ls tim
alsa-info.sh  kernelbuild  key  NVIDIA-Linux-x86-270.26.run  uberboxee
```

Once you're at that point, the remote filesystem and local filesystem act as one. You can move things into the mounted volume as you like. When you're done, just fire off `fusermount -u the_dir_you_mounted_on`:

```
oli@bert:~$ fusermount -u tim
oli@bert:~$ ls tim
oli@bert:~$ # there's nothing there because there's nothing mounted on it
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is further made simple by using SSH key authentication instead of passwords. And I've made "tim" resolve to its local network IP by editing `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: If you need to specify a different port, use the `-p [port]` option as in `sshfs oli@tim:/home/oli tim -p 1234`. If you have multiple SSH keys, and do not want to create a `~/.ssh/config` file first, you can use the `-o IdentityFile=/path/to/id_rsa` option.

Comment: I am aware of sshfs but I was more interested in one line command. Piping as it seems its a solution but for the general interest of mine it would be funny to have smv like scp.

Comment: You could certainly write a `smv` alias or a bash script to `scp`-then-'rm' if it's really a bother.

Answer (score 4):

Well SCP stands for Secure Copy (Not Secure Move ;). Joking) but for what i have read in the man pages, help sites and others there is no way to use scp to "move" a file. Just copy it.

You might try: **scp FILE user@domain: && rm FILE**

I added the && since && will only run the next command IF the first one succeeds.

Sorry could not be more helpful with the specific scp problem. I use scp a lot too.

If you want, you could use **rysnc** which i find it sometimes better than scp.

You could **rsync --remove-source-files FILE user@domain:** which i even find it better if you loose connection to the server (big files for example) since rsync can continue with even the --partial and --progress flags

Comment: +1 but I ll go with sshfs as an answer due to elegancy :)